# How can I find frequency of a specific word from document in python?

Tags: python-2.7, count, file-handling, vsm

I want to find out the frequency of a specific word from a text file. Suppose in my document i have a line "this is me is is " if i input 'is' the output should 3 if my input is 'me' output should 1. i am trying this code

```
    import re
    doc1 = re.findall(r'\w+', open('E:\doc1.txt').read().lower())
    words = raw_input("Input Number :: ")
    docmtfrequency1 =  words.count(words)
```

but it is not giving desired output

Comment: It should be `doc1.count(words)`.

Comment: what is `words.count(words)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

collections.Counter() has this covered if I understand your problem.
The example from the docs would seem to match your problem.

```
# Tally occurrences of words in a list
cnt = Counter()
for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
    cnt[word] += 1
print cnt


# Find the ten most common words in Hamlet
import re
words = re.findall('\w+', open('hamlet.txt').read().lower())
Counter(words).most_common(10)
```

From the example above you should be able to do:

```
import re
import collections
words = re.findall('\w+', open('1976.03.txt').read().lower())
print collections.Counter(words)
```

naive approach to show one way.

```
wanted = "fish chips steak"
cnt = Counter()
words = re.findall('\w+', open('1976.03.txt').read().lower())
for word in words:
    if word in wanted:
        cnt[word] += 1
print cnt
```